# Number of ring endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, morphism

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\zeta_n = e^{2i\pi/n} $ we define the following subring of $\mathbb{C}$ by,

$$\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n] = \{ P(\zeta_n) : P \in \mathbb{Z}[x]\}$$

One can easily show that,

$$\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n] = \{a_0+a_1 \zeta_n+\dots+a_{n-1} \zeta_n^{n-1} : a_i \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$

My question is about the number $N_n$ of ring endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$.

---

**My work so far :**

If $f : \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ is a ring morphism then as $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ is a subring of $\mathbb{C}$ we have, $f(m) = m$ for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. From that we easily deduce that for any element of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ we must have,

$$f\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i(\zeta_n)^i \right)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_if(\zeta_n)^i$$

And more generally,

$$\forall P \in \mathbb{Z}[x],f(P(\zeta_n))= P(f(\zeta_n)) $$

Moreover, as we know that $f(1) = 1$ and $\zeta_n^n = 1$ then $f(\zeta_n)^n=f(\zeta_n^n) = f(1) = 1$. Hence, $f(\zeta_n)$ is a $n$th root of unity, so there exists $0\leq k \leq n-1$ such that $f(\zeta_n) = \zeta_n^k$.

Therefore $N_n \leq n$. If we only considered the number of group morphisms then the answer would be $n$, but here having a ring morphism is far more restrictive, and we can see on simple examples that it should not be the case.

Indeed, $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_1] = \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_2] = \mathbb{Z}$, thus $N_1 =N_2 = 1$. Likewise, $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_4] = \mathbb{Z}[i]$ where there are only two ring morphisms, so $N_4 = 2$.

From this observation, I deduced the following conjecture
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, N_n = \varphi(n) $$

where $\varphi$ denotes the Euler's totient function.

My hope would be to show that $f(\zeta_n) = \zeta_n^k$ has to be a generator of the cyclic group of the $n$th roots of unity, that is to say $k$ and $n$ are coprimes.

Equivalently, I want to prove that the map,

$$f : P(\zeta_n) \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n] \mapsto P(\zeta_n^k) \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$$

is only well-defined when $k \wedge n = 1$ (i.e. $f(P(\zeta_n))$ does not depend on the choice of $P$). From this point on, it will be easy to prove that $f$ is indeed a ring morphism.

If $P = a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_p x^p \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $Q = b_0+b_1x+\dots+b_q x^q \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ are such that $P(\zeta) = Q(\zeta)$ where $\zeta$ is any generator of the $n$th roots of unity, then we have,

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \left( \sum_{i \equiv j [n]} a_i \right)\zeta^j = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \left(\sum_{i \equiv j [n]} b_i \right) \zeta^j$$

But somehow I have difficulties going further, does this equality for one generator implies that all coefficients involved must be equal? Is $(1,\zeta,\dots,\zeta^{n-1})$ some sort of basis? What happens when $k$ and $n$ are not coprimes, are there any simple counter examples?

---

I possibly could have missed simpler arguments. What are you thoughts on this problem and on my reasoning? Any hint or suggestion will be welcomed.

---

**Edit - current status** : Thanks to Rob Arthan's answer, we deduce that $k$ being coprime with $n$ is a necessary condition for $f$ to be a ring homomorphism which leads me to,

$$N_n \leq \varphi(n) $$

I want to show that this number is reached by defining $\varphi(n)$ different ring homomorphisms.

*Some observations:*

- As $\zeta_n^k$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity then $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_n] = \Bbb{Z}[\zeta_n^k]$.
- I realised that if,

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} a_j \zeta_n^j = 0 $$

$\qquad$ then all $a_j$ are not necessarily zero, but this was to be expected.

As Z Wu pointed out, the cyclotomic polynomials come in handy for this problem that involves primitive roots of unity. I really like this approach, but I am not supposed to know anything about cyclotomic polynomials in my algebra course, so it led me to wonder that there must maybe exist a more elementary approach.

Comment: Since the automorphisms preserve all integer relations, it preserves the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_n$, which is called the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$, whose roots are all $n$-th primitive roots of unity. So $f(\zeta_n)$ must be one of those primitive roots. Now it's left to show it can be any one of those, which is not hard. Results about cyclotomic polynomials are not trivial, you can check wikipedia.

Comment: At first glance, we do not know that $f$ is an automorphism. Thank you for this suggestion, cyclotomic polynomials are really useful, but using them here is not as elementary as I would like it to be. How do you show it could be any of those?

Comment: Yes, I should have used the word endmorphisms, my bad. I will just write an answer, but it won't be elementary though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the elementary version (which still requires a non-trivial fact).

Let us understand the structure of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ first.

It is the image of the ring map $f:\mathbb{Z}[X]\to \mathbb{C},X\mapsto \zeta_n$. Hence $$\mathop{\mathrm{Im}}f\cong\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{\ker f}$$
Let $m(X)\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$ be the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. It divides $X^n-1$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ and it is monic, using Gauss's lemma for polynomials (should be in any textbook of commutative algebra, or check this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414925/gauss-lemma-for-polynomials-and-divisibility-in-mathbb-z-and-mathbb-q?rq=1)), we know $m(X)$ divides $X^n-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, and $m(X)\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$.

Clearly $m(X)\in \ker f$. If $P(X)\in \ker f$, we have $P(\zeta_n)=0$ and thus $m$ divides $P$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. Using Gauss's lemma again, we know $m$ divides $P$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Hence $$\ker f=(m(X)),\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{(m(X))}.$$
Now we are ready to find endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$.

{Ring maps $\phi:\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{(m(X))}\to \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$}  $\Leftrightarrow$

{Ring maps $\tilde{\phi}:\mathbb{Z}[X]\to \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ s.t. $\tilde{\phi}|_{(m(X))}=0$}$\Leftrightarrow$

{Ring maps $\tilde{\phi}:\mathbb{Z}[X]\to \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ s.t. $\tilde{\phi}(m(X))=0$}$\Leftrightarrow$

{Ring maps $\tilde{\phi}:\mathbb{Z}[X]\to \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ s.t. $m(\tilde{\phi}(X))=0$}$\Leftrightarrow$

{Elements $t$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ s.t. $m(t)=0$}

The last equality uses the fact that the ring maps $R[X]\to S$ are uniquely determined by ring map $R\to S$ and the image of $X$.

Since the roots of $m(X)$ form a subset of roots of $X^n-1$, which are all in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$. We have
{Elements $t$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ s.t. $m(t)=0$}={roots of $m$}$\subset \{\zeta_n^k:0\leq k\leq n-1\}$.
Using method from Rob's answer, we know for sure that $\{\zeta_n^k:\mathop{\mathrm{gcd}}(k,n)\neq 1\}$ cannot induce a ring map. Hence

- $\#\{\text{roots of }m\}\leq \varphi(n)$ where $\varphi(n)$ denotes the Euler's totient function.
- Hence showing $\#\{\text{roots of }m\}= \varphi(n)$ is equivalent to showing that $\{\text{roots of }m\}=\{\zeta_n^k:\mathop{\mathrm{gcd}}(k,n)=1\}$.

And this fact is not trivial (i.e. the length of the whole proof is not suitable to present in mathstackexchange). A proof I know is the theorem 3.1 in this [link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=FE6EDD4CAFA67F0607DC275BB23715DE?doi=10.1.1.645.6202&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: Not the answer I was expecting. But this is an interesting way to see the problem, thank you.

Comment: @Axel As you wish, an elementary version is provided now.

Comment: I thoroughly followed your reasoning. It is far to be trivial, but I thank you for putting it within my reach. Some remarks: I assume that "ring map" means "ring morphism" but it is maybe a standard way of calling it ; I guess you used the fundamental homomorphism theorem to derive your first "equality"  ; for the last one I suppose we can take the inclusion map to be our ring morphism $R\rightarrow S$ ; finally you took twice an $m$ for different objects, which can be confusing.

Comment: The only slight problem I have is with your last statement. Let's say for instance that $n=12$ and that we take $k = 7$. Let's define the ring endomorphism $\varphi :\zeta_n \rightarrow \zeta_n^k$ then $\varphi^2 = \mathrm{Id}$ (because $7^2 = 49 \equiv 1 \mod 12$) and it only generates $2$ morphisms out of $4$ ($5$ and $11$ are left alone). But maybe I misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: @Axel Thanks for pointing that out. I searched the group structure of $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$, and it is in general not cyclic, so it in general doesn't have have a generator, thus my argument "generates exactly ..." is wrong. I will try to find another argument.

Comment: @Z Wu No problem. Thank you for your help, it helped me discover interesting and important properties on this structure.

Comment: @Axel Since the final step is equivalent to showing that all primitive roots of unity share the same minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$, which is really a non-trivial fact. I gave up for finding a suitable small and easy proof for it. Thus I just searched it and find this, check out theorem 3.1 in this paper http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=FE6EDD4CAFA67F0607DC275BB23715DE?doi=10.1.1.645.6202&rep=rep1&type=pdf .

Comment: Well, I have also seen this proof, and it seems to be the most popular way to prove the result. The proof is indeed non-trivial, it is still within my reach of understanding because I happen to know most of the notions involved, but goes way beyond my algebra course. Anyway, thank you for the link and for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First a couple of asides:
(1) a neater definition of $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ is that it is the smallest subring of $\Bbb{C}$ containing $\zeta_n$ - I think concentrating on the that fact it comprises polynomial expressions in $\zeta_n$ has led you a bit off track;
(2) $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n] = \{a_0+a_1 \zeta_n+\dots+a_{n-1} \zeta_n^{n-1} : a_i \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is only right for odd $n$: if $n = 2k$, then $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n] = \{a_0+a_1 \zeta_n+\dots+a_{n-1} \zeta_n^{k-1} : a_i \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ (because in that case, $\zeta_n^k = -1 \in \Bbb{Z}$).

That said, your conjecture is correct. As you observe, if $f : \Bbb{Z}[\zeta_n] \to \Bbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ is any homomorphism, then $f(\zeta_n)$ is an $n$-th root of unity and hence is equal to $\zeta_n^k$ for some $k$. To prove your conjecture, you need to show that $k$ and $n$ are coprime. To see this, assume we have $k = mk'$ and $n = mn'$. We need to show that $m = 1$. We have:
$$
f(\zeta_m) = f(\zeta_n^{n'}) = f(\zeta_n)^{n'} = (\zeta_n^k)^{n'} = (\zeta_{mn'}^{mk'})^{n'} = \zeta_{mn'}^{mk'n'} = 1
$$
(Here I am using the assumption that $f$ is a ring homomorphism and identities such as $\zeta_a = \zeta_{ab}^b$ and $\zeta_a^{ab} = 1$ that are easily verified).

But $\zeta_m$ is an $m$-th root of unity, hence, if $m \neq 1$, $1 + \zeta_m + \zeta_m^2 + \dots +\zeta_m^{m-1} = 0$, so we have
$$
\begin{align*}
0 &= f(1 + \zeta_m + \zeta_m^2 + \dots +\zeta_m^{m-1})\\
  &= f(1) + f(\zeta_m) + f(\zeta_m)^2 + \dots + f(\zeta_m)^{m-1}\\
  &= m
\end{align*}
$$
giving a contradiction unless $m = 1$.

[As a hint for how to find proofs like this: try some small examples. I looked at the case $n = 4$ and $k = 2$, which is a little bit too easy, but gives some clues, and then at $n = 30$ and $k = 12$, which exhibits all the issues needed for the general case.]

Comment: Thank you for this great answer and for your time. Working with polynomials has indeed led me off track, and although I thought of some key ideas you used, I did not succeed in linking them together as you did. I think that the expression you mention at $(2)$ is still correct for any $n$  - though is not the most precise -  whether $n$ is odd or even. Now, the only part remaining is showing that we can define a ring homomorphism such that $f(\zeta_n)=\zeta_n^k$ where $k$ is coprime with $n$. Is this something elementary to prove?

Comment: Apologies for the misleading comments. My brain was on strike. The minimal polynomial for $\zeta_n$ is the $n$-th [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) $\Phi_n$.

Comment: No problem, thank you for your help. Yes, that's what Z Wu originally pointed out. I will take some time to think about all of this.